Visual Studio ran into unexpected problem, and may affect some project system functions
I am new to programing so ı have no idea what to do. I was working on blazor web app project and ı was following a toturial in the video they picked up the razor page from server projet and put down to client project but when ı tried ı got this error Visual Studio ran into an unexpected problem,and may affect some project system functions. I think problem in the visual studio settings or some thing similar do can be any thing. And No application was not running.thank you
the razor file ı was talkin to :
@page "/EditVeri"
@page "/EditVeri/{id:int}"
@inject IVeriService VeriService
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly


<h3>Veri Oluştur</h3>
<br />
<EditForm Model="veri" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit" FormName="editVeri">
    <label>Kodu</label>
    <InputText @bind-Value="veri.Kodu">@veri.Kodu</InputText>
    <br />
    <label>Adı</label>
    <InputText @bind-Value="veri.Adı">@veri.Adı  </InputText>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
<br />
<br />
<a class="VeriOnay">Veri Eklendi</a>




@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    Veris veri { get; set; } = new Veris { Adı = string.Empty, Kodu = string.Empty };
    <style>
    </style>
    async Task HandleSubmit()
    {
        await VeriService.AddVeri(veri);

        await Task.Delay(2000);

    }

}

and the log file :
=====================
11.09.2024 14:01:05
Recoverable
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectSerialization.CachedProjectItemDefinition.GetMetadata(String name)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Items.SourceItemsService.<<GetAllLinkedItemsAsync>b__94_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__131`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__131`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.CopyPaste.DiskBasedCopyPasteItemHandler.<GatherExistingLinkedItemsPathAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.CopyPaste.DiskBasedCopyPasteItemHandler.<ValidateItemListAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.<>c__DisplayClass58_0.<<DoPasteCoreAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__130.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__130.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.<DoPasteCoreAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.<DoPasteAsync>d__57.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<<DropArea>b__1>d.MoveNext()
===================


What happend if you directly run this application by directly running it from the cmd by this command:  dotnet run --project ./projects/proj1/proj1.csproj .

when i ran this code terminal dotnet run --project BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2.csproj  get this message about errors ı cant ride that message because to long and now visual studio says this errors : "Type expected line 222 - Tuple must contain at least two elements line 222 - invalid token '25' in class, record, struct , or interface declaration line 222 - invalid token '(' in class, record, struct , or interface declaration line 222 - ) expected line 222 " all of these errors in a file named Componets_Pages_ EditVeri_razor.g.cs ı Dont have file like that

If you're following a tutorial then you either missed out something in the tutorial or it's a bad tutorial.  Without sight of your solution, it's very unlikely anyone will be able to figure out the problem.

I did find a solition how its fixed i have no idea but it worked. I did removed the page with problems in my case 'EditVeri' named page and rewrite it but not copyed this work for me

I get the same error when trying to drag and drop a file into visual studio. (this behaviour started when i upgraded to Version 17.11.3).
Whats weird, should i open the target folder using 'windows explorer' and directly drag n drop, thats works. Once i have done that, i thereafter successfully drag and drop files directly into visual studio ‍♀️
